# Logarithmic x axis in a stackplot MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, logarithm

I'm trying to make a stack plot from a table, to present several variables with the same x-axis. however, I want the x-axis to be logarithmic. I couldn't find any way in stackplot documentation. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve this?

I have tried using subplots instead, however, that way my graphs would not fit all on one page and I would have a lot of white space between the subplots. Therefore, I chose stackplot to make it more nice and less space-consuming.

```
tbl = readtable('usage.csv'); 

newYlabels = {'Heating (kWh/year)','Cooling (kWh/year)','Electricity (kWh/year)'};  
stackedplot(tbl,[{2:16},{17:27},{28:35}],'XVariable',[1],'DisplayLabels',newYlabels);
```

Here is the output of the code:

[image: text]

Here is an image of what I'm trying to make, but the x-axis needs to be the real variable (\beta) in logarithmic scale

[image: text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stackedplot` has unfortunately no logarithmic axes option, and since it creates a `StackedAxes` instead of a normal `Axes` object, there is no way to changes this.

If the only reason you want to use `stackedplot` is to have less white-space, you might want to check out [`tight_subplot` on the Matlab FEX](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight_subplot-nh-nw-gap-marg_h-marg_w). This would allow you to just do: `set(ax, 'XScale', 'log')`.

You can however take the `log` of your `x`-data, and add that to the table:

```
tbl = readtable('outages.csv');     % sample data
tbl = sortrows(tbl, 'OutageTime');  % sort by date

% make x vector; for example just row numbers
x = (1:size(tbl,1)).';
xlog = log10(x);

% add x to table
tbl.Xlog = xlog; 
tbl.X = x;

% plot normal x
f = figure(1); clf;
s = stackedplot(tbl, {'Loss'}, 'XVariable', 'X');
xlabel('rows');

% plot log(x)
f = figure(2); clf;
s = stackedplot(tbl, {'Loss'}, 'XVariable', 'Xlog');
xlabel('log(rows)')
```

Normal:
[image]

Log:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I switched to tight_plot. It's not as nice of stackedplot, but it works!